# Why is there no Set method in c++ for a repeated protobuf field?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

i am using the following `.proto` file:

```
message Header
{
    enum MessageType
    {
        UNKNOWN = 0;
        CONNECT = 1;
        DISCONNECT = 2;
        UPDATE = 3;
        REQUEST = 4;
        SUBSCRIBE = 5;
        UNSUBSCRIBE = 6;
    }
    required MessageType msgType = 1;
}

message DataSet
{
    optional string id = 1;
    optional string value = 2;
}

message StdMessage
{
    required Header header = 1;
    repeated DataSet dataSet = 2;
}
```

Here is the compiled StdMessage class:

```
class StdMessage : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
 public:
  StdMessage();
  virtual ~StdMessage();

  StdMessage(const StdMessage& from);

  inline StdMessage& operator=(const StdMessage& from) {
    CopyFrom(from);
    return *this;
  }

  inline const ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet& unknown_fields() const {
    return _unknown_fields_;
  }

  inline ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet* mutable_unknown_fields() {
    return &_unknown_fields_;
  }

  static const ::google::protobuf::Descriptor* descriptor();
  static const StdMessage& default_instance();

  void Swap(StdMessage* other);

  // implements Message ----------------------------------------------

  StdMessage* New() const;
  void CopyFrom(const ::google::protobuf::Message& from);
  void MergeFrom(const ::google::protobuf::Message& from);
  void CopyFrom(const StdMessage& from);
  void MergeFrom(const StdMessage& from);
  void Clear();
  bool IsInitialized() const;

  int ByteSize() const;
  bool MergePartialFromCodedStream(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream* input);
  void SerializeWithCachedSizes(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream* output) const;
  ::google::protobuf::uint8* SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(::google::protobuf::uint8* output) const;
  int GetCachedSize() const { return _cached_size_; }
  private:
  void SharedCtor();
  void SharedDtor();
  void SetCachedSize(int size) const;
  public:

  ::google::protobuf::Metadata GetMetadata() const;

  // nested types ----------------------------------------------------

  // accessors -------------------------------------------------------

  // required .Header header = 1;
  inline bool has_header() const;
  inline void clear_header();
  static const int kHeaderFieldNumber = 1;
  inline const ::Header& header() const;
  inline ::Header* mutable_header();
  inline ::Header* release_header();

  // repeated .DataSet dataSet = 2;
  inline int dataset_size() const;
  inline void clear_dataset();
  static const int kDataSetFieldNumber = 2;
  inline const ::DataSet& dataset(int index) const;
  inline ::DataSet* mutable_dataset(int index);
  inline ::DataSet* add_dataset();
  inline const ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::DataSet >&
      dataset() const;
  inline ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::DataSet >*
      mutable_dataset();

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:StdMessage)
 private:
  inline void set_has_header();
  inline void clear_has_header();

  ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet _unknown_fields_;

  ::Header* header_;
  ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::DataSet > dataset_;

  mutable int _cached_size_;
  ::google::protobuf::uint32 _has_bits_[(2 + 31) / 32];

  friend void  protobuf_AddDesc_xplane_2eproto();
  friend void protobuf_AssignDesc_xplane_2eproto();
  friend void protobuf_ShutdownFile_xplane_2eproto();

  void InitAsDefaultInstance();
  static StdMessage* default_instance_;
};
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in the compiled/generated cpp file, there is no `set_header` or similar function in the `StdMessage` class. my question is, how can i set the header of the `StdMessage`??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not the mutable_header() method that returns a pointer to the Header instance?

Comment: just in this seconde i saw it, also. but do you/smb else know, why there is no set_header or whatever function? why do i have to use this mutable stuff?

Comment: Not sure, but for repeated instances it works in a similar way, you call to add_whatever() and it will return a pointer that you can then modify. Maybe it's a design decision to avoid copying data here and again.

Comment: kk, move ur comment to answer and i will mark it! thanks! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the mutable_header() method to get a pointer to the already created Header instance.